# Trying to combine two queries into a single query for performance

Tags: sql, database, oracle, performance, optimization

I am having an Oracle SQL Database issue, the problem I am facing is that I am trying to perform two aggregate operations but I am making two queries to do them. I am scanning the same table (TableOne) twice. I have a join that needs to happen in order to make the aggregation as well. Is there a way to leverage case statements to make the entire query in one go?

```
select PAR, SUM(PLANQUANT) AS VALONE
from
(select ODRP.PAR, ODRP.PLANQUANT from TableOne ODRP
inner join TableTwo LOC 
on ODRP.LOCID = LOC.LOCID and LOC.LOCNAME like '%_USD'
where ODRP.TYPEID IN (5,6)) 
group by PAR;

select PAR, SUM(PLANQUANT) AS VALTWO
from
(select ODRP.PAR, ODRP.PLANQUANT from TableOne ODRP
inner join TableTwo LOC  
on ODRP.LOCID = LOC.LOCID and LOC.LOCNAME like 'BAT_USD'
where ODRP.TYPEID IN (1)) 
group by PAR
```

I believe such a query would start as

```
select PAR, SUM(PLANQUANT) AS VALONE, SUM(PLANQUANT) AS VALTWO
from
(select ODRP.PAR, ODRP.PLANQUANT from TableOne ODRP
inner join TableTwo LOC  
on ODRP.LOCID = LOC.LOCID and LOC.LOCNAME like '%USD'
where ODRP.TYPEID IN (1, 5, 6))
```

and then I know I need case statements in at least the group by and probably the join as well?

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You are aware that a literal underscore in a LIKE condition is a wildcard character, right? `'%_USD'` matches any string that is at least **four** characters long, of which the last three are USD, and the fourth from the right can be *anything*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use conditional aggregation.  In this case, I think the query would be:

```
SELECT ODRP.PAR,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ODRP.TYPEID IN (1) AND LOC.LOCNAME LIKE 'BAT_USD'
                THEN ODRP.PLANQUANT
                ELSE 0
           END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN ODRP.TYPEID IN (5, 6) AND LOC.LOCNAME LIKE '%USD'
                THEN ODRP.PLANQUANT
                ELSE 0
           END)
FROM TableOne ODRP JOIN
     TableTwo LOC  
     ON ODRP.LOCID = LOC.LOCID 
WHERE ODRP.TYPEID IN (1, 5, 6) AND LOC.LOCNAME LIKE '%USD'
GROUP BY ODRP.PAR
```

Comment: In the conditional sum for TYPEID in (5, 6), you don't need to repeat the condition on LOCNAME - since it is the same as in the ON condition of the join. (Which by the way was LIKE '%_USD' - you are missing the underscore, but it is not clear what the OP meant by it anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this...

```
select ODRP.PAR, 
SUM(CASE WHEN ODRP.TYPEID IN (1)
        THEN ODRP.PLANQUANT ELSE 0 END) VALTWO
, SUM(CASE WHEN ODRP.TYPEID IN (5,6) 
        THEN ODRP.PLANQUANT ELSE 0 END) VALONE
from TableOne ODRP
inner join TableTwo LOC  
on ODRP.LOCID = LOC.LOCID and LOC.LOCNAME like '%_USD' 
group by ODRP.PAR
```

Add the condition for LOCNAME in the CASE statement as well. I didn't realize that was also different for both the queries.